# Do the Borg exist in the Mirror Universe?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

Do the Borg exist in the Mirror Universe?
If so, have they encountered the Empire or Alliance?

Or, have the Prime Borg Ever crossed into the Mirror Universe?

Otherwise, how is it that the Borg could be unaware of Alternate Universes in which they could invade with ease or at the least ally themselves with more Borg?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but my gut feeling is no, the Borg haven't encountered the Empire or Alliance, because the events of TNG and VOY where humanity came in contact with the Borg likely didn't happen in the mirror universe, so they would have stayed in their area of the Delta quadrant. But that is just a guess.

Comment: Nothing in canon speaks to this, as far as I know. (It’s certainly possible, of course, that a mirror Kevin Uxbridge, one who relishes destruction and chaos, wiped out the mirror Borg millennia ago.) Since we know of nothing like this occurring, I think it’s safe to assume that the Borg do exist in the Mirror Universe, and that their MO is very much different than the Prime Universe Borg Collective’s.

Comment: They're a "kinder, gentler" Borg who seek recruits.  "Compliance is voluntary."

Comment: “how is it that the Borg could be unaware of Alternate Universes in which they could invade with ease” — they may or may not be aware of alternate universes, but even if they were, why would they be interested in them? There’s plenty of species left in their own universe who haven’t yet had their quality of life improved by the Borg. “or at the least ally themselves with more Borg?” Allies are irrelevant. When have the Borg ever sought out alliances with anyone?